# How can I prove R[x] is integrally closed iff R is integrally closed ? (R: integral domain)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

$R$ is a integral domain. How can I prove $R[x]$ is integrally closed iff $R$ is integrally closed?

Comment: Hi, this is Exer 4.18 of Eisenbud, there are plenty of hints in the Appendix. 

Comment: The way the question is phrased makes it sound like homework.  What have you tried so far?  Is one of the two directions easier than the other?  